# Converting a byte array to string and back

Tags: python, pyzmq

My python back end uses byte arrays like this `'\x00k\x8bEg'` as IDs. In order to correctly display them in my nodejs front end I use the operations seen bellow

```
hex_data = binascii.hexlify('\x00k\x8bEg')
text_string = hex_data.decode('utf-8')
```

this might return back something that looks like this : 006b8b4569

I would like to revert this operation and get back my original ID from the string object that I create, so as to be able to select the desired item from a dictionary.

I tried doing

```
raw_bytes = binascii.unhexlify('006b8b4569')
```

but the result is not my original ID.

How can I successfully perform this translation back and forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reverse the steps properly.

```
>>> bytestream = b'\x00k\x8bEg'
>>> hex_data = binascii.hexlify(bytestream)
>>> str_data = hex_data.decode('utf-8')
>>> str_data
'006b8b4567'
>>> binascii.unhexlify(str_data.encode('utf-8')) == bytestream
True
```